# Counting the number of documents in a view with Lotus Notes Formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have a button in the toolbar that mails selected documents to a mailbox. The Problem is that I have no idea how to make the button formula code run for every selected document. As it stands now it will only ever run once, regardless of how many documents are selected. This  is not ideal as the users often have many documents to mail in.

It is impossible to create an agent to do this as I do not have access to the development access to the database itself. People have also told me that the code will run for each selected document, but I have tested this, and it does not from a toolbar button.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to get the selected documents and work on each of them without having to modify the database, but it is tricky, and I needed some time to figure it out.

Your Code in the toolbar has to do a
@Command([Compose]; "" : "yourActionDb.nsf" ; "StartAction" )

The database "yourActionDb.nsf" (in this case on local) has to have a form (called StartAction here) and here is the trick: 
In the "QueryOpen" of the Form the context is still the view... So you can use code like:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uiviw as NotesUIView
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection
Set uiviw = ws.CurrentView
If not uiviw is Nothing then
  set dc = uiviw.Documents
  ...your code comes here
End if
```

Unfortunately this trick is not possible in Formula Language, as only an Agent has the possibility to act on selected documents, and every called agent will have the wrong context...

You have to close this form afterwards (either try to set continue = False in the queryopen or do a uidoc.Close later), but here you have to find out yourself what fits best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your testing is correct -- you can't run a toolbar macro on selected documents.  You'll need an agent for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you create a Formula agent (same formula content as your toolbar button) and set the target as "Selected Document" then in your Toolbar button, add :

@command([toolsrunmacro];"Agent Name or Alias here");

- it'll run the formula agent against every selected document. Set the agent target to be Selected Dcouments.